# How can I read excel document from Document library in SharePoint 2007 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, document-library, 2007, jquery, spservices

I want to read the contents of excel file stored in document library in SharePoint 2007. SP2007 does not support Sandbox solution and I can't deploy farm solution. I need JavaScript based solution.

What I tried so far?

I have followed following [Retrieve Data from SharePoint Document Libraries (using SPServices)](http://consulity.com/content/SPServices.aspx).

The code given here works, but I need to get the content of file. How can I get my code?

Any reference or advice is most valuable.

Comment: This is not a Sharepoint related. You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to read the file, then pass the result to a javascript library that supports Excel, like https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/

Comment: @AymKdn Please read the question again. This question is directly pointing to SharePoint 2007. SharePoint 2007 does not support REST API, it can only work with SPService or any other approach I am looking for.

Comment: I'm not talking about REST API in my comment....